# Does ASP. NET core still requires hosting with. NET support

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I plan to develop website in ASP. NET core. In past i wrote few ASP. NET website but as far as i remember it requures to buy special hosting which needs to have. NET installed. I would like to know whether nowdays is it enough to have cheap hosting without. NET support to pubslih my ASP. NET core website or i still need to buy hosting which has. NET support?

Comment: Since .NET Core can run on Linux then by implication no, you don't need dedicated .NET Framework hosting, because that would only run on Windows. But you'd still need to check the specification of the hosting and whether it would support .NET Core. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.0 can help you understand the basic hosting requirements. Then you can search for hosting providers with suitable specs. It's also quite common to host these apps in containerised or serverless environments, where the specifics of the host are abstracted away.

Comment: As I know that .net core running on Linux server, but personally I never test it. I always use .net core on Windows server and it is running perfectly. .NET will always compatible with Windows, that's why I always use Windows server. If you are planning to host it on Windows server, then you can try Asphostportal.com. I use this provider to deploy my .net core project.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core can be published to either use an installed .NET Core runtime *or* self-contained, in which the required parts of the framework are actually published along with the app. In .NET Core 3.0, you can actually publish a .NET Core app as an entirely self-contained single executable file.

In either to publish self-contained (whether in a single executable or not), though, you must target a particular runtime environment when you publish (i.e. Win x64, Linux x64, etc.) You can then only put the app in that actual environment, i.e. if you publish for Windows, you can't deploy that to a Linux box. However, you could simply re-publish for Linux instead.

If you target an installed runtime, similar to how .NET Framework works, then you can publish once and deploy anywhere, assuming the destination has the .NET Core runtime installed.

Long and short, you are not locked into any one particular way of deploying. If you want a framework installation, you can do that. If you want self-contained, you can do that as well.

That said, you should still avoid *shared* hosting. They usually do not support .NET Core at all or don't keep up with deploying new versions. Additionally, deploying self-contained is generally going to be disallowed to prevent users uploading rogue things. You can get a VPS all to yourself for like $5/mo, so there's really no value proposition to shared hosting nowadays, anyhow.